# .htaccess Redirect 301 Strange behaviour

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, server, web-hosting, vs-web-site-project

I have a new Website that consists of 1 Domain and 2 Subdomains:

Domain:

```
www.bluepuma.at
```

Subdomain:

```
werbeagentur.bluepuma.at
werbetechnik.bluepuma.at
```

The old website only had 1 Domain: `www.bluepuma.at`
Now I wrote a bunch of Redirects to redirect the old directorys from the old website to the new one:
I wrote them in the .htaccess which is in the root domain directory in `www.bluepuma.at`:

```
Redirect 301  /werbeagentur-bluepuma/wer-ist-bluepuma/  https://werbeagentur.bluepuma.at/
Redirect 301  /werbeagentur-bluepuma/jobs/  https://werbetechnik.bluepuma.at/werbetechnik/jobs-lienz
Redirect 301  /agentur/online-marketing/suchmaschinenoptimierung/ https://werbeagentur.bluepuma.at/online-werbung/online-marketing
Redirect 301  /agentur/online-marketing/suchmaschinenmarketing/ https://werbeagentur.bluepuma.at/online-werbung/online-marketing
Redirect 301  /agentur/online-marketing/social-media-marketing/ https://werbeagentur.bluepuma.at/online-werbung/social-media-marketing
Redirect 301  /agentur/online-marketing/newsletter-marketing/ https://werbeagentur.bluepuma.at/online-werbung/online-marketing
Redirect 301  /agentur/online-marketing/videomarketing/ https://werbeagentur.bluepuma.at/online-werbung/produktfotografie
Redirect 301  /agentur/online-marketing/analyse-controlling-reporting/  https://werbeagentur.bluepuma.at/online-werbung/online-marketing
Redirect 301  /agentur/online-marketing/marketing-konzepte-planung/ https://werbeagentur.bluepuma.at/online-werbung/online-marketing
Redirect 301  /agentur/online-marketing/  https://werbeagentur.bluepuma.at/online-werbung/online-
```

Now I have the problem, that the Redirect also work on the Subdomain:

Example:
If I open `https://werbeagentur.bluepuma.at/werbeagentur-bluepuma/wer-ist-bluepuma/`
I get redirected to `https://werbeagentur.bluepuma.at/` according to this redirect statement:

```
Redirect 301  /werbeagentur-bluepuma/wer-ist-bluepuma/  https://werbeagentur.bluepuma.at/
```

But this should not be possible.
The Redirects should only affect the main domain. For example:

`www.bluepuma.at/werbeagentur-bluepuma/wer-ist-bluepuma/`  should get redirected to `https://werbeagentur.bluepuma.at/`

Do you have any ideas why this could be?

Another strange behaviour: If I open

`www.bluepuma.at/agentur/online-marketing/suchmaschinenoptimierung/`

I get to the page

`https://werbeagentur.bluepuma.at/online-werbung/online-marketingsuchmaschinenoptimierung/`

I have no idea what causes this error.

Thanks for your answer and your time!

Comment: Where does the main domain and subdomains point to on the filesystem? Do you have other directives in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Why shouldn't that be the case? Most likely you implemented those redirections at a location where _all_ http hosts you are using see them. Don't use a stupid distributed configuration file (".htaccess") but instead implement those rules in the real http server's host configuration. In that host where they should get applied. That is why you have different hosts in the first place: to be able to make a difference.